# Why is the array not in the tableview?

Tags: ios, swift

For some reason the array is not being placed into the table view any reason why? The `CellWithIdentifier` is correctly instantiated, in the storyboard the cell has the same identifier. It is also confirmed that the array is populated. I have also already connected the datasource and delegate on the storyboard. Why is the tableview not showing the array?

```
let TextQuery = PFQuery(className: "submit")
    TextQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        var object = objects as! [PFObject]

        for i in 0...object.count-1{
            self.arrayOftexts.append(object[i].valueForKey("text") as! String)
            print(self.arrayOftexts)
        }

    })
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arrayOftexts.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = myTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = arrayOftexts[indexPath.row]
    print("added to tableview")
    return cell
}
```

Comment: did you call `tableview.reloadData()` at all? (should be after your for loop probably)

Comment: you entered the following method?  func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int{
        return 1
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forget to add `self.tableView.reloadData`, --> this is refresh your Data

```
for i in 0...object.count-1{
        self.arrayOftexts.append(object[i].valueForKey("text") as! String)
        print(self.arrayOftexts)
    }
// add the following line 
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

**Choice 2**

```
for i in 0...object.count-1{
        self.arrayOftexts.append(object[i].valueForKey("text") as! String)
        print(self.arrayOftexts)
    }


// add the following line 

if self.arrayOftexts>0
{
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
self.tableView.reloadData()
})
}
else
{
// set to tableview as hidden
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView!) ->   Int {

    return 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As everyone has said, you are probably missing `tableView.reloadData()`.

What I usually do is this:

```
var arrayOftexts : [AnyObject]? {
    didSet {
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

This will allow you to reload the table when the array is updated.